# Coordinates of foreignObject HTML elements in SVG space

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG file with an XHTML table. I want to connect portions of the table with SVG drawing (via JavaScript). For example, in the following file I want to place each of the yellow circles centered on the right ends of the red borders:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 650" version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Connect</title>
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    table { border-collapse:collapse; margin:0 auto; }
    table td { padding:0; border-bottom:1px solid #c00;}
    circle.dot { fill:blue }
  ]]></style>
  <foreignObject x="100" width="800" height="600" y="400"><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><table><thead><tr>
    <th>Space</th>
  </tr></thead><tbody>
    <tr><td><input name="name" type="text" value="One"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="name" type="text" value="Two"/></td></tr>
  </tbody></table></body></foreignObject>
  <circle class="dot" id="dot1" cx="100" cy="100" r="5" />
  <circle class="dot" id="dot2" cx="200" cy="100" r="5" />
</svg>
```

How can I best find the location of an arbitrary HTML element in global SVG coordinate space?

*For simplicity, feel free to ignore browser resizing, and any transformation stacks that may wrap the `<foreignObject>`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I have come up with, in action: [HTML Element Location in SVG (v2)](http://phrogz.net/svg/html_location_in_svg_2.svg)

```js
// Find the four corners (nw/ne/sw/se) of any HTML element embedded in
// an SVG document, transformed into the coordinates of an arbitrary SVG
// element in the document.
var svgCoordsForHTMLElement = (function(svg){
  var svgNS= svg.namespaceURI, xhtmlNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
  var doc  = svg.ownerDocument;
  var wrap = svg.appendChild(doc.createElementNS(svgNS,'foreignObject'));
  var body = wrap.appendChild(doc.createElementNS(xhtmlNS,'body'));
  if (typeof body.getBoundingClientRect != 'function') return;
  body.style.margin = body.style.padding = 0;
  wrap.setAttribute('x',100);
  var broken = body.getBoundingClientRect().left != 0;
  svg.removeChild(wrap);
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  return function svgCoordsForHTMLElement(htmlEl,svgEl){
    if (!svgEl) svgEl = htmlEl.ownerDocument.documentElement;
    for (var o=htmlEl;o&&o.tagName!='foreignObject';o=o.parentNode){}
    var xform = o.getTransformToElement(svgEl);
    if (broken) xform = o.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(xform);

    var coords = {};
    var rect = htmlEl.getBoundingClientRect();
    pt.x = rect.left; pt.y = rect.top;
    coords.nw = pt.matrixTransform(xform);
    pt.y = rect.bottom; coords.sw = pt.matrixTransform(xform);
    pt.x = rect.right;  coords.se = pt.matrixTransform(xform);
    pt.y = rect.top;    coords.ne = pt.matrixTransform(xform);

    return coords;
  };
})(document.documentElement);
```

And here's how you use it:

```
// Setting SVG group origin to bottom right of HTML element
var pts = svgCoordsForHTMLElement( htmlEl );
var x = pts.sw.x, y = pts.sw.y;
svgGroup.setAttribute( 'transform', 'translate('+x+','+y+')' );
```

Caveats:

- It works perfectly in Firefox v7
- It works for Chrome v16 and Safari v5, except:

  - It does not work well if the browser zoom has been adjusted.
  - It does not work if the `<foreignObject>` has been rotated or skewed, due to [this Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71819).
- It does not work for IE9 (XHTML isn't showing up, and `getTransformToElement` does not work).